# Ad interactivity to list tag in beeswarm viz using D3 v4

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I have been trying to add some interactivity to a chart using D3, but based on a list tag in the HTML.

What I want to is, when people hover the list items (Brazil, Americas, Africa etc), to the dots to highlight, like `opacity: 1;` or `fade` effects, something that will highlight the continent's dots when I hover their names.

[Here is the code](http://codepen.io/voltdatalab/pen/KzrNGo?editors=0010)

I tried variations to the short snippet below, which has worked for me in the past, for more simple charts:

```
    cell.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.data.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.data.y; })
  .attr("fill",function(d) { if(d.data.id === "Brasil")return "#000";      
  if(d.data.region === "África")return "rgba(255, 224, 102, 0.4)"; 
  if(d.data.region === "Americas")return "rgba(112, 193, 179, 0.4)"; 
  if(d.data.region === "Europa")return "rgba(36, 123, 160, 0.4)";
  if(d.data.region === "Ásia")return "rgba(250, 166, 26, .4)";if(d.data.region === "Oceânia")return "rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.4)"})
  ;

  d3.selectAll(".legenda")
 .on("mouseover", function (d) {
 d3.select (d.region)
 .style("opacity", 1);
 })
 .on("mouseout", function (d) {
 d3.selectAll(".legenda")
 .style("opacity", .4);
 });
```

I haven't figure it out how to bind with the data in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
d3.select(d.region);
```

You are not selecting any circle (besides that, if you are selecting several circles it should be `selectAll`, because `select` just selects the very first element it finds).

But the good news is that there are several ways to do what you want. One of them is applying a class according to the continent, when you create the circles:

```
cell.append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d){ return d.data.region})
```

Then, you can select all the circles belonging to that class, and apply the opacities the way you want:

```
d3.selectAll(".legendas")
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
    var thisContinent = this.id;
    d3.selectAll("circle").attr("opacity", 0);
    d3.selectAll("." + thisContinent).attr("opacity", 1);
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    d3.selectAll("circle").attr("opacity", 1);
});
```

For that to work I changed the class of the `li` tag to "legendas" (because it was firing twice, once for `li` and once for `ul`).

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/regYyw

Comment: No worries! Hey, just a tip if I may: avoid the diacritics (I speak Portuguese too). Try to write all classes, IDs, fields, CSVs etc in lower case and without diacritics. Cheers.

Comment: Its great, tks for the help. I wanted to single out Brazil and the Median, so it stayed in the viz all the time even when we hovered the legend, but I could not do it. Also I don't know why the hover is not working in the final project, just in CodePen. But those are minor problems. Muito obrigado, meu caro!

Comment: De nada! The hover problem is possibly CSS related. Besides that, you have the voronoi, that makes d3 mouseover events way more complicated. I'll check your link when I'm on my laptop.

Comment: Yeah, I though about that, but its the exact same code in both (codepen and the final project), weird. Some some other code is overwriting it.